# Kubernetes mongo DB user creation

Tags: mongodb, jenkins

I am trying to create a Mongo db user using the following method via Jenkins Job

```
kubectl exec -i ${POD} -- sh -c "mongo --eval 'db.createUser({user:"DBusernmae",pwd:"test",roles:[{role:"dbAdmin",db:"training"}]})'"
```

receiving following error

```
2021-02-09T10:50:38.641+0000 E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: DBusernmae is not defined :
```

Please help me on this

Comment: any one have solution fo this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proper quotation: your first `"` starts with `mongo` and ends with `DBusernmae`

Comment: Can you please provide the exact syntax,
I have tried all the possibilities, but it failed

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote `"`:

```
kubectl exec -i ${POD} -- sh -c \
  "mongo \"mongodb://admin:pwd@localhost:27017\" --eval 'db.createUser({user:\"DBusernmae\",pwd:\"test\",roles:[{role:\"dbAdmin\",db:\"training\"}]})'"
```

I'd be grateful if somebody found a nice way to do this that doesn't require the community or enterprise operators though.